# My .desktop file is not executing the application

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

I am new to Linux and Ubuntu in general. I want to create a .desktop file for the sublime application. Here is what I have..

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=/home/chris/Downloads/Sublime Text 2/sublime_text
Name=Sublime Text
Icon=/home/chris/Downloads/Sublime Text 2/Icon/48x48/sublime_text.png
```

It wont execute the application for some reason.
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried escaping the spaces in the paths? For example:

```
Exec=/home/chris/Downloads/Sublime\ Text\ 2/sublime_text
```

and

```
Icon=/home/chris/Downloads/Sublime\ Text\ 2/Icon/48x48/sublime_text.png
```

Answer (score 1):

In debian escaping doesn't work. I tried different variations for `Exec` and `Path` both with spaces in the name and found working the following combination:

```
Exec="/home/chris/Downloads/Sublime Text 2/sublime_text"
Path=/home/chris/Downloads/Sublime Text 2
```